# Laravel 5.4: Model Update Failure produces error (SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column...)

Tags: php, sql, laravel, exception, heroku

I have read all of the questions that have a similar title and believe this to be somewhat different.

First, my code (below) is an **update** to an existing person record.  I update 2 fields based on a condition.  The complete exception lists only a portion of the generated SQL and does show it to be an update query.

That's why I'm confused because this isn't a column count issue, as I see it.

The code:

```
if(<some condition>)) {
    $user              = Socialite::driver('linkedin')->user();
    $person            = Person::find($id);
    $person->avatarURL = $user->avatar;
    $person->updaterID = $id;
    $person->save();
}
```

The person tables has both of these columns.

The complete error text:

```
SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 
(SQL: update `person` set `avatarURL` = urltext, `updateDate` = 2017-07-19 15:02:28 where `personID` = 357)
```

Now, I know the above SQL does NOT run when dumping into a query editor because there are no quotes and such as there normally should be.

I'm not sure why it's being displayed that way.

I tried the following SQL on the same table and received the same error.

```
UPDATE `person` SET `midName`='blah' WHERE `personID`='357';
```

Error:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1136: 1136: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
SQL Statement:
UPDATE `bl5hod18fm0zc1zh`.`person` SET `midName`='blah' WHERE `personID`='357'
```

Lastly, the only other details which could be relevant is that this is a JawsDB mysql implementation on the heroku cedar-14 stack.

Comment: try to remove the single quote wrap for the 357 .. personID is integer with auto increment attribute right or should i say the primary key ..

Comment: I didn't put the values in quotes.  It's how it's getting displayed in the error text, however.  Also, I just did it again now without quotes and still get the same error.

Comment: have you tried to query in your Database ? is it working ?

Comment: Yes that's in the question.  I did the query against the database with several tables.  Only the person table seems to be giving me this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  This was a tricky problem that I've solved and I'm posting the answer to save someone some time in the future, hopefully.

The problem was a trigger that was saving the person record to a person_history table.  The insert to the person_history table was failing despite the error indicating otherwise.